# storing a array of coordinates in mongoose and then retrieving the same type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

i have this schema

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var fenceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
FenceID : {type: String},
loc :{
    type: {
        type: String,
    },
    coordinates: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
}
,
created : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var fences = mongoose.model('fence1',fenceSchema);
module.exports = fences;
```

However whenever I store a JSON using this schema

```
var pointB = [[43.647228, -79.404012],[43.647869, -79.377363],[43.622821, -79.375429],[43.622082, -79.40385     7]];     
var post =  newFence1({ FenceID: "XSDF", loc :{type: 'Polygon', coordinates: pointB}});
```

And when I try to retrieve the document from the db

```
newFence1.find({}).lean().exec(function(err,docs){
     console.log('docsss '+ JSON.stringify(docs));
     console.log ( 'coordinates'+docs[0].loc.coordinates);
}
```

The docs[0].loc.coordinates doesn't stay the same form as an array of coordinates instead its just all the numbers delimitated by comma e.g from [[12,12],[12,3]]  to ===> 12,12,12,13. How do I ensure it stays that way because I have to pass those results for some other query.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to come under the category of cannot reproduce. Perhaps you can consider this full listing example to see where the actual differences are in your actual code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var fenceSchema = new Schema({
  "loc": {
    "type": { "type": String },
    "coordinates": [Schema.Types.Mixed]
  },
  "created": { "type": Date, "default": Date.now }
});

var Fence = mongoose.model( 'Fence', fenceSchema );

var myPoly = [
  [43.647228, -79.404012],
  [43.647869, -79.377363],
  [43.622821, -79.375429],
  [43.622082, -79.403857]
];

var post = new Fence({
  "loc": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": myPoly
  }
});

console.log(
  "Before Save:\n%s", JSON.stringify( post, undefined, 4 ) );

post.save(function(err,doc) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(
    "After Save:\n%s", JSON.stringify( doc, undefined, 4 ) );

  Fence.find({ "_id": doc._id },function(err,docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(
      "When Found:\n%s",JSON.stringify( docs, undefined, 4 ) );
    process.exit();
  });

});
```

Probably worth mentioning that the following notation is exactly the same as the "Mixed" type, by implicit "lack of" and defined type:

```
var fenceSchema = new Schema({
  "loc": {
    "type": { "type": String },
    "coordinates": []
  },
  "created": { "type": Date, "default": Date.now }
});
```

This gives the following output, basically:

```
Before Save:
{
    "_id": "54605dd572dab34c6405a042",
    "created": "2014-11-10T06:40:21.020Z",
    "loc": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                43.647228,
                -79.404012
            ],
            [
                43.647869,
                -79.377363
            ],
            [
                43.622821,
                -79.375429
            ],
            [
                43.622082,
                -79.403857
            ]
        ]
    }
}
After Save:
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "54605dd572dab34c6405a042",
    "created": "2014-11-10T06:40:21.020Z",
    "loc": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                43.647228,
                -79.404012
            ],
            [
                43.647869,
                -79.377363
            ],
            [
                43.622821,
                -79.375429
            ],
            [
                43.622082,
                -79.403857
            ]
        ]
    }
}
When Found:
[
    {
        "_id": "54605dd572dab34c6405a042",
        "__v": 0,
        "created": "2014-11-10T06:40:21.020Z",
        "loc": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    43.647228,
                    -79.404012
                ],
                [
                    43.647869,
                    -79.377363
                ],
                [
                    43.622821,
                    -79.375429
                ],
                [
                    43.622082,
                    -79.403857
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
]
```